# Where is the wiring loose on this AngularJS call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, post

I am learning AngularJS and I believe my page has a wire loose.

The page has a TEXTAREA and I have entered 'aaa' in the TEXTAREA. The TEXTAREA is bound to an ng-model of input. The AngularJS below is intended to both monitor for changes from outside and with some granularity save data to the server:

```
var UnixyTalk = angular.module('UnixyTalk', []);
UnixyTalk.controller('OutputController', ['$scope','$http', '$timeout', '$q',
   function($scope, $http, $timeout, $q)
        {
        var last_input = $scope.input;
        var repeatEr = function(data, status, headers, config)
            {
            var interval = !(config && config.time)? 1000 : 
            (1000 - (config.time - (new Date()).getTime()));
            angular.extend($scope, data);
            console.log(data);
            $timeout(function()
                {
                $http.post('/ajax/listen',
                    {
                    'cache': false, 
                    'params': {'conversation': 0},
                    'timeout': 1000,
                    }).success(repeatEr).error(repeatEr);
                $http.post('/ajax/say',
                    {
                    'conversation': 0,
                    'params': {'text': $scope.input, 'time': new
                      Date().getTime()}
                    });
                }, interval);
            }
        repeatEr();
        }
    ]);
```

And the server side is reporting that it is getting an empty POST dictionary.

How should I be listing a dictionary if I want to post a QUERY_STRING's key-value pairs (i.e. 'field1=value1&field2=value2' rather than a JSON object)? Any other errors in this code?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure, but your timeout closure looks odd to me. Any other errors... [maybe](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/IBM_403_plugboard.agr.jpg).

Comment: Thanks: I've simplified that.

Comment: Yes... it still looks odd to me... why `.success(repeatEr)`?

Comment: Angular posts data over using application/json, not as "form data", what language is your backend written in?

Comment: My back end is Python / Django; I'm trying to avoid using jQuery for now until I have some AngularJS discipline, but one AngularJS post said that jQuery has an easy function call to convert from JSON to form data. The server side is not complaining out of receiving JSON when form data is expected; it is reporting empty POST form data.

Comment: The .success(repeatEr) is what I have now, for a chat project, to keep querying the server to see if other participant(s) have said anything new since the last check. Maybe it should be implemented differently, but the intent is to periodically poll the server for new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using python, you could create a function to get the posted data, something like:

```
def getPost():
    if  'CONTENT_TYPE' in request.META and request.META['CONTENT_TYPE'].startswith('application/json'):
        return json.loads(request.body)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return request.POST.dict()
```

Then you can just call that function to get your post params

Comment: Thank you; Django was treating request.POST as an empty dict after the client had sent well-formed JSON (and not form data) data.